# How can show the next value from a value saved in a table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I'm trying to create an initial number when the user saves the initial number of an invoice will continue with next value

Table example working:

```
|invoice_nums|
  |id|   |invoice_num|
   1        3010
|invoices|
  |id|   |invoice_num| |amount|
   1        3011         1000
   2        3012         1000
   3        3013         1000
```

Table example not working when i change the invoice_num value from InvoiceNums:

```
|invoice_nums|
  |id|   |invoice_num|
   1        2010
|invoices|
  |id|   |invoice_num| |amount|
   4        2014         1000      ###SHOULD BE 2011
   5        2015         1000      ###SHOULD BE 2012
```

Here is my controller:

```
  def new
   @num_ini = InvoiceNum.first
   @num_last = Invoice.last
   @trick = Invoice.count(:all) 
  end
```

Here is my view:

```
<% @sum= "%06d" % (@num.invoice_num.next.to_i + @trick.to_i) %>
<%= @sum %>
```

I tried this in the view

```
<%= @sum= (@num_last.invoice_num.to_i  || @num_ini.invoice_num.to_i )+ 1   %>
```

Also I tried this in the view:

```
<% if @num_ini.invoice_num.to_i > @num_last.invoice_num.to_i   %>
    <%= @sum= @num_ini.invoice_num.to_i + 1 %>
<% else %>
    <%= @sum=@num_last.invoice_num.to_i + 1 %>
<% end %>
```

Please somebody can help me?

I'm trying to continue the invoice_num according the last invoice_num from the invoice_nums.

All help can be accepted.

Comment: What's logic for invoice_num to be 2010 ??

Comment: How do you go about changing the initial number? Are you manipulating the `AUTO_INCREMENT` setting on the table? You haven't even specified what database back-end you're using here.

Comment: actually the change is kinda meaningless, because if you only had 1 record, still `.last` should work, you don't need the `||`, the `||` is for the condition of an empty table, if you know you won't face that condition then just go with `.last`, also the `@sum=` could be removed, since you're just printing the line directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  INITIAL_INVOICE_NUMBER = 2009
  before_create :set_invoice_number

  def set_invoice_number
    (Invoice.maximum(:invoice_number) || self::INITIAL_INVOICE_NUMBER) + 1
  end

end
```

Note:

I made the initial `2009` because of the `+1` either that or change the line to a trinary condition

Comment: +1 better than mine this is definitely the way to go unless he wants to be able to manipulate the seed independently. Although you need to add `self.invoice_number =` or this step has no impact.

Comment: In our projects we usually use a config table, so for this example it would be something like `MyConfig.find_by(name: 'initial_invoice_number')` or whatever class name, keeps configs dynamic and changing them doesn't need a deployment.

Comment: are u using rails 2? that's way too old man, I've tested it on both rails 3 and 4, should work, don't know about rails 2

Comment: oh it's ok thanks by the way...now I'll try to use that logic into rails 2.

Comment: if the keyword `maximum` doesn't work, you could always use `select('max(invoice_number) as whatever')`

Comment: How can I use your model code in my view please? still don't know how to resolve this.

Comment: This isn't for calling in views, this is a callback function that's used when creating a new invoice, it would set the new invoice number. I don't understand what you want in the views

Comment: Here in is question i'm posting an example view and demo.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25857642/how-can-create-an-initial-new-value